# Mongo - Empty object to query string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
transporters.count({ '$and': [ {} ] })

transporters.count({ })
```

Is it the same?

Is it possible the empty object cause speed issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes both queries are considered the same.

This can be seen in the [explain output](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) of both queries:

```
> db.test.explain().count({})
{
  "queryPlanner": {
    "plannerVersion": 1,
    "namespace": "test.test",
    "indexFilterSet": false,
    "winningPlan": {
      "stage": "COUNT"
    },
    "rejectedPlans": [ ]
  },
....
```

and:

```
> db.test.explain().count({$and:[{}]})
{
  "queryPlanner": {
    "plannerVersion": 1,
    "namespace": "test.test",
    "indexFilterSet": false,
    "winningPlan": {
      "stage": "COUNT"
    },
    "rejectedPlans": [ ]
  },
....
```

The `explain()` output of both queries are identical, meaning both queries will execute the same way.